# gradle: @Entity symbol not found

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, gradle

I've these dependencies into my `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    java
    checkstyle
}

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.eclipse.microprofile:microprofile:2.1")
    compile("org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.2-api:1.0.0.Beta2")
    compile("org.hibernate.ogm:hibernate-ogm-bom:5.4.1.Final")
    compile("org.hibernate.ogm:hibernate-ogm-mongodb:5.4.1.Final")
}
```

This is my code:

package main.java.io.espaidoc.persistence.domain;

```
@Entity
public class Reference {

    private String id;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Nevertheless, I'm getting this compilation error:

```
Reference.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
@Entity
 ^
  symbol: class Entity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For JPA 2.2, you'd have to use:

```
compile("javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2")
```

, since [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.2-api) says:

> Note: This artifact was moved to:
>
> javax.persistence » javax.persistence-api » ${jpa-api.version}

JPA 2 - 2.1 are still available under "org.hibernate.javax.persistence".